# Basic problems about counting

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Given $4$ cells of a partition namely $\left\{1\right\},\left\{2\right\},\left\{3\right\},\left\{4\right\}$ in how many ways we are able to distribute $\left\{3\right\},\left\{4\right\}$ to   $\left\{1\right\},\left\{2\right\}$ $\color{red}{\text{and}}$ distribute $\left\{3,4\right\}$ to $\left\{1\right\}\left\{2\right\}$ such that $\color{red}{\text{the two distributions have nothing in common}}$.

Assuming these cells $\left\{1\right\},\left\{2\right\}$ are fixed.

The total situations that $\left\{3,4\right\}$ can be distributed to $\left\{1\right\},\left\{2\right\}$ are
: $$\color{green}{\left\{1\right\}\left\{2\right\}\left\{3,4\right\}}$$$$\color{green}{\left\{1,3,4\right\}\left\{2\right\}}$$$$\color{green}{\left\{1\right\}\left\{2,3,4\right\}} $$

And the total situations that $\left\{3\right\}\left\{4\right\}$ can be distributed to $\left\{1\right\},\left\{2\right\}$ are  (considering the condition that these two situations have nothing in common):
$$\left\{1\right\}\left\{2\right\}\left\{3\right\}\left\{4\right\}$$$$\left\{1,3\right\}\left\{2\right\}\left\{4\right\}$$$$\left\{1,4\right\}\left\{2\right\}\left\{3\right\}$$$$\left\{1\right\}\left\{2,3\right\}\left\{4\right\}$$$$\left\{1\right\}\left\{2,4\right\}\left\{3\right\}$$$$\left\{1,3\right\}\left\{2,4\right\}$$$$\left\{1,4\right\}\left\{2,3\right\}$$$$\color{blue}{\left\{1,3,4\right\}\left\{2\right\}}$$$$\color{blue}{\left\{1\right\}\left\{2,3,4\right\}}$$

The two blue cases are the ones that have been counted in the previous situation.

So the summing the first case and the second case and subtracting their intersection gives:
$$\color{green}{3}+10-\color{blue}{3}=10$$
The problem is that I cannot see any pattern or any nice pattern for these kind of problems, can someone explain what is the way to count all the possible solutions?
I think this is related to  inclusion-exclusion argument and also is related to [distribute distinct objects into distinct bins](https://brilliant.org/wiki/distinct-objects-into-distinct-bins/) , but I don't know how to use them.

Comment: {1}{2}{3}{4} and {1}{2}{4}{3} are same?

Comment: @aryanbansal,yes they are the same thing, and $\left\{1,2\right\}$ and $\left\{2,1\right\}$ are also the same thing ($1,2$ are examples)

Comment: For the first case, did you mean the first line to read $\{1\}\ \{2\}\ \{3,4\}$? Also, why do you not include (for example) $\{1,3,4\}\ \{2\}$ in the second group?

Comment: @rogerl, I've edited lots of things, please read from the first and you will see why I don't do that

Comment: This is hard to follow. I think I may have understood what you want: It seems that you want to count partitions of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ in which $1$ and $2$ are in separate sets, in two different groups, one in which $3$ and $4$ are in the same set and one in which they're in different sets. Is that correct? If so, since you've already counted this particular case, you seem to be missing some form of generalization. What are "these kind of problems" that you want to count? Various generalizations are conceivable (e.g. $1$ and $2$ could be fixed or there could be $n$ of them, etc.).

Comment: @joriki, you are totally right, actually I'm trying to generalize Bell's numbers where we have $B_{n+m}$, there is a formula for counting the partitions of a set with $m+n$ elements but I'm truing to count the partitions when our sets are more than $2$, I can do that easily with writing and the strategy I'm using for that is right, but I cannot formulize that at all.

Comment: @joriki, assume we have three sets with cardinality $m,n$ and $p$, I'm trying to find all the partitions on this set  , in other words I want $B_{m+n+p}$ the formula I've found is :
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{m}\sum_{v=0}^{p}{n\brace k}{m\brace j}z\binom pvB_v\left[{n\brace k}{m\brace j}z\right]^{p-v}$$ , and $z$ is something that I'm asking in my question

Comment: Are you referring to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3535041)?

Comment: @joriki, yes that's right, I got what you explained but I want to count the partitions when we have more than two  sets

Answer (score 0):

let's say there are m elements fixed and you need to arrange n elements in above prescribed.

It's n is less than 5 or 6 but after that it's difficult (atleast the method i am using there could be a simpler method).

let's say all the n elements goes in m elements which have $m^n$ cases.

Then let's say  k element does not go in the m elements(we have to select k things which go) and n-k elements goes inside m elements. No of ways = ${n \choose k}\ m^{n-k}\times$ (number of ways of partition of subset with k elements in disjoint sets=$B_k$)

For k=1 , it's 1

for k=2 , it's 2

k=3 , it's 5

k=4 , it's 15

k=5 , it's 52

k=6 , it's 203

then becomes more difficult to count the ways . It involves bell numbers (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set).

So our final answer is $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}m^{(n-k)}S_k$

Comment: Well these are actually Bell numbers and your method has been discussed already at this site, and there is a well-known explicit formula for computing that (the formula is a specification of another less known formula), but in my case by using your method then can you explain how we can give $10$ (which is my final answer)

Comment: let's say 3 and 4 are contained in 1and 2 are 4 ways (3 and 4 have 2 options). Now one of them is contained in  1 and 2  and one is not , is ${2 \choose 1}2\times$(number of ways of partition of set containing 1 elements=1)=4. Now both are out is number of partition of set containing 2 elements=2. So total 4+4+2=10ways.

Comment: I guess you are actually saying there are four cases:$$\text{ I})$$Neither $3 \text{nor} 4$ are paired with $1\text{and}2$  $$\text{ II})$$one of $3,4$ is paired with both $1$ and $2$ $$\text{ III})$$one of $3,4$ is paired with $1 \text{or} 2$  and the other is left single  $$ \text{ IV})$$ one of $3,4$ is paired with  $1 \text{or} 2$ **and** the other is also paired with the other unpaired element

Comment: summing gives $7$ possible cases and we also should consider the other situation and their intersection (after that we will get $10$), the way you calculate is not true since you get 10 from just one of the two situations –

Comment: the number of cases are 'n+1' , see my solution!!!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly from the comments what you’re trying to do, I’d do it like this:

$n+m+p$ elements can be partitioned by first partitioning $n$ elements into $k$ sets, then adding $j$ of the $m$ elements to the $k$ existing sets and partitioning the remaining $m-j$ elements into $l$ new sets, then adding $r$ of the $p$ elements to the $k+l$ existing sets and partitioning the remaining $p-r$ elements into new sets, so

$$
B_{n+m+p}=\sum_{k=1}^n\left\{n\atop k\right\}\sum_{j=0}^m\binom mjk^j\sum_{l=1}^{m-j}\left\{m-j\atop l\right\}\sum_{r=0}^p\binom prr^{k+l}B_{p-r}\;.
$$

Comment: should not we choose $j$ elements from $m$ elments and distribute them into $k$ existing sets and then partitioning the $m-j$ elements into $l$ new sets?

Comment: @user715522: You're right of course; and likewise for $r$ of $p$ elements; I've added the corresponding binomial coefficients.

Comment: and can we write $B_{m-j}$ instead of $\sum_{l=1}^{m-j}{m-j\brace l}$?because after selecting $j$ elements from $m$ elements and distributing them into $k$ existing sets then we are left with $m-j$ elements that makes a set of cardinality  $m-j$ that can be partitioned in $B_{m-j}$ ways.

Comment: @user715522: No, we need to keep track of the number $l$ of sets we partition them into, since we then distribute $r$ of the $p$ elements over the $k+l$ existing sets.

Comment: I've never seen this generalization on internet (+1) and I guess you are the first one who formulized that (congratulations!), but duo to curiosity I'm going to post my question at this site with more details ASAP .